Re-using built-in USB port to charge battery
I'm dipping my toes into using LiPo batteries for supplying power to small devboard projects, currently with an LOLIN S2 mini.
So I got hold of a MH-CD42 module, which seemed like a safe way to start with.
I came up with this example schematic to illustrate what I'm trying to do: to use the onboard USB port to power the board and charge the battery when connected, and to power the board with the battery if USB is disconnected. In this schematic I would need to flip the switch to accomplish this but I wonder if there is a way to wire this up so that a switch is not needed and the board does not reset when (dis)connecting the USB connection. Any thoughts on this are appreciated.


"to power the board and charge the battery when connected", you can't charging the battery while connecting to the load (which is your ESP32 board). You need a load sharing switch, read Li-Ion Battery Charger and Load Sharing System.

Wemos is probably not optimised for battery power operation. A board designed for battery operation requires attend to the specification of every components it used and with the proper charger and load sharing circuitry. Such as  Sparkfun ESP32 Thing which has load sharing circuitry and low dropout voltage and low sleep current for battery operation.

I can see what you are trying to do (make use of the already present USB connector), but I think that you are looking at it the wrong way, as well as trying to make the MH-CD42 work (or rather, connect it up) in ways that it isn't really meant for.
Forget about using the onboard USB of the WEMOS.
You should connect the VOUT to the VBUS as you are meant to (check the usage and diagram in the link to the MH-CD42 that you provided):

Provide a separate female USB connector (or alternate power supply connector) to VIN of the MH-CD42, and apply power that way (instead of trying to gain "dual usage" from the USB connector onboard the WEMOS).
In this manner, you are using the MH-CD42 correctly - it will automatically do the "switching" for you and no power glitches will occur when the USB (or whatever) power supply is removed (from VIN).
In addition, you no longer have to worry about dual-purpose/dual-direction power lines - that seems like a recipe for disaster.

An alternative method (without the MH-CD42) can be found in this answer to How to create automatic dual battery changeover/switching circuit for uninterruptible power?

Thanks! Do you think the idea is bad in general or just in combination with the MH-CD42? I'm just interested if it is possible to do it since the principle seems useful and elegant to me, but I lack EE knowledge so it's currently hard for me to understand if this is just a bad approach in general. I could imagine something along these lines could be more easily achieved when designing your own pcb but that's not something I plan to do due to safety risks, hence my use of devboards and modules like this.

It just seems like a bad idea, if you are using a MH-CD42,, as the MH-CD42 is designed to do the switching for you, so let it do so. However, if you don't use a MH-CD42 then your "switching" idea is a good one, and that is basically what the additional link to Olin's answer (on SE.EE) does. However, if you are already using a unit (i.e. the MH-CD42) that basically does what Olin's answer does, then just let that unit do the work for you. Why bother re-inventing the wheel? Forget about the onboard USB connector. The devboard is just that... for development. Later, a production unit would ...

... use a standalone ESP-8266EX (or whatever variant) IC (without the devboard PCB - you would be using a custom PCB of your own making), that has no USB connector (at least not a USB connector wired to VBUS, but to VIN instead), and so your design will still work. Hopefully that makes sense. :-) See also, What IC does the MH-CD42 battery/5v power board use? as it is an interesting read.

FWIW, a variant of Olin's answer has just been posted, with a mechanical switch, as an answer to a different question, over on SE.EE.
